# How to dynamically create Angular(15) component?

Tags: angular, angular15

I have a function which would create an In memory angular component, add it as a declaration for an In memory Angular Module and then compile the same

something like this:

```
createComponent(template, selector) {
     @Component({
      selector: selector,
      template: template
    })
    class AngularComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit
    {
      @Output() onAfterViewInit = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

      ngOnInit(): void {
       // some event
      }

      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // some event
      }
    }

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AngularComponent],
      imports: [],
      exports: [],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    class TemplateModule {
    }
    const compiled = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
}
```

This used to work for Angular 10. But, since Ivy compiler is introduced now, it would not work for Angular 15. Could anyone please suggest updates for the above function to make it compatible for Angular 15?

**Edit**

I tried the following:

```
    class AngularComponent {
    }
    const componentType = Component({ template: html, selector: selectedComponent})(AngularComponent);
```

This works until I add `implements OnInit, AfterViewInit` for `AngularComponent`

Once I add the same, I get following error:

`error NG2007: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.`

**EDIT 2**

Based on @Anton's comment, I made following changes:

```
createComponent(template, selector) {
    @Directive()
    class AngularComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
      @Output() onAfterViewInit = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

      ngOnInit(): void {
        // method call
      }

      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.onAfterViewInit.emit();
      }
    }

    const angularComponentType = Component({
      template: html,
      selector: selectedComponent
    })(AngularComponent);
}
```

Now the `ng build` works, but on `ng serve` I am getting error on browser console:

```
Error: NG0202: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.
This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.

Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 0 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making changes and proper testing here is what worked for me:

Created a component as base class

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    template: ''
})
export class AngularComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() onAfterViewInit = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.onAfterViewInit.emit();
    }
}
```

And then created a dynamic component extending the base class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
createComponent(html, selector) {
    const angularComponentType = Component({
        template: html,
        selector: selector
    })(class extends AngularComponent {
          ngOnInit(): void {
            localfunction(this);
          }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your example works, just add Angular decorator for this.

```
 @Directive()
 class AngularComponent {}

 const componentType = Component({ template: html, selector: selectedComponent})(AngularComponent);
```

And then use it somewhere in your code:

```
this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentType, {
     injector: this.injector,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.
Though, 'ng serve' or 'ng build' works for your suggested solution, on runtime i get `NG0202` error on browser

I have update my question with the same. Please have a look

Comment: Looks like using decorator inside a method is not allowed now. Which is why using `@Directive` or `@Component` gives me the error

Comment: Check the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nc85dv?file=src/main.ts

Comment: Yes, I did something similar. Will be posting detailed answer in sometime

Thanks again :)